# How to start another Activity?

Tags: android, button

hi 
    i have bulid a rss reader for with help of ibm tutorial.I have created all the classes for it and i gave the following url "http://www.mahindrasatyam.com/rss/rssfeeds/news_updates.xml".
which has the rss feeds.
i wanted to get description of each article on click of item in list.
for that the code 
is

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
     Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

     Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
     b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
     b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
     b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

     itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

     startSubActivity(itemintent,0);
 }
```

but it was showing an error **startSubActivity(itemintent,0);**

and to remove error needed o implement its method which is

```
private void startSubActivity(Intent itemintent, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```

i want to load the description with the class Show description which is

```
public class ShowDescription extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.showdescription);

        String theStory = null;


        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

        if (startingIntent != null)
        {
            Bundle b = startingIntent.getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
            if (b == null)
            {
                theStory = "bad bundle?";
            }
            else
            {
                theStory = b.getString("title") + "\n\n" + b.getString("pubdate") + "\n\n" + b.getString("description").replace('\n',' ') + "\n\nMore information:\n" + b.getString("link");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            theStory = "Information Not Found.";

        }

        TextView db= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storybox);
        db.setText(theStory);

        Button backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                finish();
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

but there is no view loaded on click of list item

can some one help me to solve this problem

Comment: The line containing '`});`' looks wrong - in setOnClickListener.  The balanced parenthesis is before the `new`, and the whole thing looks suspicious in the extreme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `startSubActivity`, use `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult` instead. Have a look [at the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) to learn how to use them.

Comment: Thanx for help Stephen i have tried these methods but after using these methods my application crashes when i click the item in the list .

Answer (score 2):

You could try just using `startActivity(itemintent)` instead of `startSubActivity(itemintent,0)`? To my knowledge, you should be out of having to implement the startSubActivity method.

Comment: hi Rasmus i have tried this way but my application crashes on item click when i  use this method in this way

Comment: Could you please provide the error you get when using `startActivity`? From what i know, you should be just fine with using `startActivity` instead of `startSubActivity`.

Comment: My Application just crashes .I tried to load the screen shot but i couldn't .when i click the item the message come Sorry The application RSS reader has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.                is there any change required in manifest file

Comment: If you use eclipse and want to see the error through logcat, you can connect to the phone with a cable and click the "Debug" button in the top right corner of the eclipse window (If it's standard configured). There you should be able to see the error message.